# OnChange handler being triggered only in the first instance of the Component, even though it is triggered on different instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have a component which is essentially a list of Menu items with each menu item having a unique form.

I need to render this component in two instances, in the HTML page and in a Modal.

In a scenario where the HTML page has already been rendered and I open the modal, and perform actions on the Menu item, the onChange Handler is being triggered only in the HTML page and not in the Modal, even though the action is triggered in the Modal.

This is the my component

```
class MyComp extends Component {

 toggleHandler(){
   const {owner} = this.props;
   //perform an action
   console.log("owner is : ", owner)
 }

 render(){
   return(
      <div class="checkbox_style">
         <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="checkbox"
            onClick={this.toggleHandler}
          />
      </div>
  );
 }

}
```

I am using this in two instances

```
class ContentComp extends Component{
 render(){
    {this.renderOtherComps}
    <MyComp {...this.props} owner="home" />

 }
}

class HeaderComp extends Component{
 render(){
    {this.renderOtherComps}
    <Modalbutton //launches ModalComp />    
 }
}

class ModalComp extends Comp{
   render(){
     //Using some common modal details
     <MyComp {...this.props} owner="modal" />
   }
}

class HomeComp extends Component{
 render(){
    {this.renderHeaderComp}
    <MyComp {...this.props} owner="home" />
    {this.renderFooterComp}
 }
}
```

The ModalButton is triggered ModalComp loads up with MyComp.

Triggered the checkbox in MyComp and and the console.log prints

-> owner is home

Expected output is

-> owner is modal

Because of this the re- rendering doesn't work in ModalComp.

I have used shouldComponentUpdate and tried setting flags to return false if the Modal is opened. Doesn't stop this behaviour

Comment: This feels like one of those questions that would definitely benefit by having a codesandbox. I think you will have better response if you can provide a working example. Try codesandbox.io to make one. :)

Comment: sure, sounds logical. Will create one.